# Android Maps control

Tags: android, android-intent, maps, actionview, mapactivity

If I use the Intent to fire up default maps app on emulator/device, how can I gain control on the clicks/touch on the map.
e.g. I want to find all Pizza places in my location. It is damn easy if I use  geo URI.
                String uri = "geo:"+ 39.967571 + "," + -75.532123 + "?q=pizza";
                startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
Once the map is started I loose control, I want to be able to extract some values based on where the user has clicked.

If I extend MapActivity I am not getting what I desire i.e. list of business based on a parameter. 
Intent myIntent = new Intent(YYYYY.this, XXXX.class);
                YYYYY.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
This will fire up XXXX activity which extends MapActivity. How do I get the list of Pizza places based on current location. I tried using geocoder with parameters but results weren't reliable at all.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use the Intent to fire up default maps app on emulator/device, how can I gain control on the clicks/touch on the map

You don't. That's not your app.

> If I extend MapActivity I am not getting what I desire i.e. list of business based on a parameter.

You're going to have to write the "list of business based on a parameter" logic yourself, with some third-party source of "list of business" data.